Android Studio kotlin, set camera iso, exposure and other
So I'm making android app for photos, and i stuck at point where i need to make photos with custom exposure and iso set by user, but I'm not really sure how to do this
I read some articles and official documentation, but I didn't really find way to implement this (at least in kotlin)
